# Memory leaks with audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying

Tags: objective-c, audio, memory-leaks

I have created an iPhone card game with a BGM and some sound FX. The game is working fine when I cancel the sound voids, but it seems to generate memory leaks each time I link a sound to a card. For each sound void, the code is like this:

```
- (void)cardLostSound {
NSString *pathForCardLostSoundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
pathForResource:@"CardLost" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *cardLostSoundFile = [[NSURL alloc]
initFileURLWithPath:pathForCardLostSoundFile];
cardLostPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:cardLostSoundFile
error:NULL];
[cardLostSoundFile release];
[cardLostPlayer prepareToPlay];
[cardLostPlayer play];

[self performSelector:@selector(audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:)
withObject:cardLostPlayer afterDelay:[cardLostPlayer duration]];//This is a hack I
found to force application of void audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying, which doesn't seem to
work on its own…
```

}

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {

if (player == self. cardLostPlayer){
    [self.characterComboPlayer release];

else if (player == self.cardBackPlayer){
    [self.cardBackPlayer release];
}//etc.
```

}

Having audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying release the players doesn't seem to do a thing against memory leaks. Without it, the app always crashes after the same amount of time. With it, the game is slow, but lasts longer. Then, the app crashes anyway. When I just cancel these lines, I don't have any crash. Is there a way to keep the sounds, while having the app run smoothly and without memory leaks?

Comment: What do you mean "seems to cause a memory leak"?  And what's the crash exactly?  And why aren't you using ARC?

Comment: You are not setting `cardLostPlayer`'s delegate to self, which is why you are not getting the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` message.

Comment: Also, the code you posted makes no sense: you set what I assume is the backing ivar of cardLostPlayer in `cardLostSound`, and test for it in your callback, but you release a different property. Is this a typo?

Comment: Also you may want to clarify exactly what the problem is. You first seem to say that crashes after a longer time without the callback, then say that you don't get a crash if you "cancel these lines," by which I assume you mean the callback. Does it crash with the callback or doesn't it? And what kind of crash is it?

Comment: Thanks nhgrif!!! I refactored the whole project to ARC and it did the trick!